Is it acceptable to end a question with "Thank you" type statements?
I've seen questions that end in a variety of "Thank you" statements.
Some just a simple:  
Thanks for your help.

To some that are fairly bizarre like this one (that I just made up):  
Thanks in advance to all those who have worked tirelessly 
to expend their efforts to help me.

My question(s): 1) is it acceptable for these "Thank you" statements to be included in a question? 2) When found, should "Thank you" type statements be edited out of questions? ... Or is it a matter of "extent" (as in the examples I've given)?
Personally, I feel that every (OK, most) question askers would like to thank those that help them, and those providing answers know that (in general), the askers' appreciate the efforts of those providing answers. And as "This goes without saying", it shouldn't be said, in the question. If desired, a "Thank you" comment to any helpful answers should be welcome and sufficient.
I have not always felt this way, and I may have even been guilty of including "Thank you" statements in my questions in the past. 

These notes are removed on StackOverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

@ThomWiggers - According to a post by Jeff Atwood - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/200482 on that page, only "greetings" like "Hi/Hello" are automatically removed, and specifically states that "Thanks" statements are not removed. Does this apply to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com?

"...with respect to our previous recommendation to use “Thanks in advance”. Some hackers feel this connotes an intention not to thank anybody afterwards" http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Questions and Answers on SE are not about interaction with other users, but about transferring knowledge.
Any unnecessary text should be avoided to make this knowledge resource as accessible and understandable as possible.
This includes salutations, humor, thank-yous, and any information unnecessary to get the question/answer across.
Instead, appreciation is usually shown by upvoting helpful contributions and accepting the best answer to your questions (if satisfying). It is also possible to reward exceptional answers by manually assigning a bounty.
Source:
meta.stackoverflow on that topic.

Yes, we hate fun (standard emoticons are implied).
